# Photo.SE is trying to give me malware?

Tags: bug, status-completed, security

I'm just browsing SO questions and I see an ad for the Photo SE. This one in particular:
[image]

I'm intrigued, so I click on it, and do you know what greets me? This:

[image]

So I was just wondering why this was showing up? I'm running Chrome 9.0.587.0 on Windows 7 (64-bit)

---

It should be noted that just navigating to photo.stackexchange.com does not cause this warning to popup. However if you try to click on that exact question you still get this warning.

Comment: If you view the source of the page, you can see that a user by the name of Matt Grum posted an answer and included images that come from his website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have removed the images in question for now.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like Matt Grum's Website is hosting malware - intentionally, or unintentionally, because he links to his site in a response to that question, it is throwing the malware warning.

Comment: So should we remove the link?

Comment: @yes, i don't have mod on there, i've asked on our internal chat for someone to do it (if you have mod on there go for it)

Comment: That seems to have fixed it - Chrome 7 doesn't report anything suspicious now, and I suspect different versions are using the same anti-malware service.